# Swapping letters in a word (Java)

Tags: java

I have this question: [image: question]

I tried solving the question through various integer values of i and j. But the most suitable ones I could find was 1 and 5. However even then the output was near to the correct version and not properly correct. Here's my code:

```
public class test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String str = "Gateway";
        int i = 1, j =5;
        String first = str.substring(0, i);
        System.out.println(first);
        char second = str.charAt(j);
        System.out.println(second);
        String third = str.substring(i + 1, j -1);
        System.out.println(third);
        System.out.println(str.charAt(i));
        System.out.println(str.substring(j + 1));
        
    }
}
```

This results in the output: `G a te a y`

Is there something wrong with my code or am I taking the wrong integer values? I've been trying to figure out but certainly that has been of no help. I hope somebody can point out the mistake I'm doing.

Comment: Hmm. The assignment talks about concatenating *5* strings. I think your code there only prints **3** strings.

Comment: Besides, looking at this it should print `Gateway` as `charAt(1) and charAt(5)` are ofc `a` itself. What do you expect however given those inputs

Comment: The string you get when you do `String first = str.substring(0, i);` ends right before the index at position `i` on `str`. So then what do you think happens when you do `String third = str.substring(i + 1, j -1);`? It ends right before the index at `j-1`. So it ends at `j-2`. Which is not what you're being told to do.

Comment: Please do not include text as images. If you want help from volunteers, please make it as easy as possible for them to help you. I cannot read the text from these images.

Comment: Thank you for the replies! I figured out the mistake myself of putting 'j - 1' instead of 'j' which made me think I was doing something wrong with the position.  

And gotcha NoMadMaker.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two things:

1. The choice of i and j, i = 1, and j = 3 (basically the indices of the letters to be swapped).
2. `String third = str.substring(i + 1, j - 1);`

should be

`String third = str.substring(i + 1, j);`

as substring goes till the index just before the one mentioned in the second argument, i.e if you want the substring to include j-1, you have to set the parameter as j.

Comment: Ahh gotcha! I forgot that it should be "j" instead of "j -1". Thank you! I'll have to revisit the concept again to remember it. have a nice day :)

Answer (score 0):

Java is a zero-based index language. Use these values:

```
int i = 1; // the first "a"
int j = 3; // the first "e"
```

`substring()`’s end parameter is *exclusive* - see bug fix below!

Try coding like this for clarity and debug-ability:

```
String first = str.substring(0, i);
char second = str.charAt(j);
String third = str.substring(i + 1, j); // Note: corrected bug!
char fourth = str.charAt(i);
String fifth = str.substring(j + 1);

System.out.println(first + second + third + fourth + fifth);
```

See [live demo](https://ideone.com/VSFL0v).

Comment: @GhostCat because OP is obviously a total beginner and is almost there, but stuck and a little bit of generous help now will help OP’s journey of learning to code.

Comment: have you seen that the result should be "Getaway"?

Comment: @evg_ny and "Getaway" is what it prints. I’ve added a link to a live demo.

Comment: Ahh gotcha! I forgot that it should be "j" instead of "j -1". Thank you! I'll have to revisit the concept again to remember it. have a nice day :)